# Python accesses multiple lists in a nested list. What's going wrong?

Tags: python, arrays, list, nested-lists

Python doesn't support multidimensional arrays, but I thought this workaround would be easy enough. It's just not working though. Here's my code

```
mat = [ [ None ] * 3 ] * 3
mat[0][0] = 1
return mat
```

Output

```
[[1, None, None], [1, None, None], [1, None, None]]
```

Why is it changing mat[1][0] and mat[2][0]? If I ask it to print mat[0][0] it just gives me 1 like it should.

Comment: The actual related one is - [Python list of lists, changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/python-list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

Comment: If you want to do a lot with multi-dimensional arrays, then you should look at numpy.

Comment: Thanks @Anand. I couldn't for the life of me find this answer.

Comment: You may find this article helpful: [Facts and myths about Python names and values](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/names.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.